# Double click does not highlight text CKEditor

Tags: javascript, meteor, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am currently using CKEditor5 in my meteor application, but when I double click a text in CKEditor, the text does not get highlighted. I have instantiated like this:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor';
const editorBox = {};

const self = this;
self.editors = new ReactiveVar('');
const dataModelId = self.data.dataModelId;
const id = `#upsert-data-model-property-description-${dataModelId}`;

ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector(id), {})
  .then((editor) => {
    self.editors.set(editor);
    editorBox[id] = editor;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the css from ckeditor imported?

Comment: I do not have a specific import for ckeditor's CSS in the code

Comment: That's where my question was directing to. Does it work if you import all necessary Files as shown in the ckeditor documentation examples?

Comment: This is the only line of code I am importing

```import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'```